# Dragging JPanel's inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, drag

I am adding `JPanel` to `JFrame` on a `JButton` click. It adds the `JPanel` to the frame. The button will keep on adding the `JPanel` to `JFrame` on click event. There are no limitations. I am adding the `JPanels` to a `List` as well when a button is clicked. I did this because of adding the `MouseMotionListener` using for loop to handle Dragging of JPanel's.

The problem which I am facing now is with the drag. When I add the first `JPanel` with a click and if I drag it, it follows the Mouse cursor coordinates properly. When I add a second `JPanel`, it too follows the mouse perfectly. After adding the second, if try to drag the first JPanel the first JPanel seems to follow different coordinates like, the initial position will change to some other location. I don't know where have I done the mistake. Please help me resolve this problem. Please go through the code below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JButton jb;
    List<JPanel> mypanels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    public MyFrame() {
        jb = new JButton("Add Panel");
        jb.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 50);
        setSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        add(jb);
        setVisible(true);
        initialize();
    }


    public void initialize() {

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBounds(150,150,200,200);
                panel.setBackground(Color.black);
                mypanels.add(panel);
                add(panel);
                repaint();
                handleDrag();
            }
        });

    }

    public void handleDrag(){
        for(int i=0;i<mypanels.size();i++) {
            final int j = i;
            mypanels.get(i).addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                    me.translatePoint(me.getComponent().getLocation().x, me.getComponent().getLocation().y);
                    mypanels.get(j).setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
                }

            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MyFrame();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you storing the bounds of the JPanels somewhere in your GUI data model?

Comment: No I am not storing any Bounds of JPanels.

Comment: Then, how do you know where they are after they have been dragged?

Comment: I don't know the implementation details behind why you're doing this, but have you considered using something like [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)? (Also, its [Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)). Just making sure that you aren't unnecessarily reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @Gilbert , I was using me.getComponent().getLocation().x at translate(). I thought it gives the location of that particular JPanel on which a click event occurs.

Comment: @Brian I have tried with JInternalFrame but for some reasons it doesn't suit my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- maybe have look at [Moving Windows by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/)
- do not combine `ComponentMover` with `ComponentResizer` in the same time

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your handleDrag method is adding a new anonymous Listener to every JPanel when just one JPanel is added to the List. The listener only needs to be added once, if more than one listener is added the behavior will get weird.

here is an updated handleDrag method

```
    public void handleDrag(JPanel panel){
    final JPanel p = panel;
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                me.translatePoint(me.getComponent().getLocation().x, me.getComponent().getLocation().y);
                p.setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should declare the method argument itself final rather than just an alike object in the method body.

Answer (score 5):

Joe is correct, this is what I made of the handleDrag method in my project:

```
public void handleDrag(final JPanel panel){
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
             x = me.getX();
             y = me.getY();
        }
    });
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            me.translatePoint(me.getComponent().getLocation().x-x, me.getComponent().getLocation().y-y);
            panel.setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
        }
    });
}
```

This way the panel doesn't make an initial 'jump' when clicking on it.